# EF Core: Getting table with Include, but Include should not get one column

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have those models (Entity class stores Id)

```
    public class TeachingProgramme : Entity
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TeachingProgrammeFile> TeachingProgrammeFiles { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class TeachingProgrammeFile : Entity
    {
        [Required]
        public byte[] Content { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int TeachingProgrammeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public TeachingProgrammeFileType FileType { get; set; }

        public virtual TeachingProgramme TeachingProgramme { get; set; }
    }
```

And a service for getting TeachingProgramme with it's files, but without file data (TeachingProgrammeFile.Content):

```
            db.TeachingProgramme teachingProgramme = await _context.TeachingProgrammes
                .Include(x => x.TeachingProgrammeFiles)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == request.TeachingProgrammeId);
```

How can I optimize it for NOT getting Content every time from database? It takes a big load of unnecessary data, since I only need TeachingProgrammeFile Name and Id

Comment: It's not an `Include` thing per se; that's just the `JOIN`; don't pull the data you don't want (write `Select(.. props apart from Content here..)`) so it's never put into the `SELECT` and hene the DB never sends it

Comment: Did you try adding extension method Select at the end of LINQ? I think it should filter on DB level.

Comment: Do you need these entities for modification? Or jest for returning via controller?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv for modification. I tried those selects and it's not working

Comment: Then you have to redesign your entities. And move Content to navigation property (other table). Otherwise you'll stick with detached entities updates.

Comment: *it's not working* - what does that even mean?

Comment: Can you please exactly tell me how do you see this Select? Let's try a real example and I'll tell you

Comment: Project the needed columns into another class like this:

var teachingData = await _context.TeachingProgrammeFiles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t=>t.TeachingProgrammeId==request.TeachingProgrammeId).Select(t=> (t.Name , t.FileType, t.TeachingProgrammeId));

If you *must* use the entity, then use the entity constructor than the tuple.

Comment: @MayurEkbote, OP needs these entities for modification. Custom projection is not an option.

Comment: That's not the original question though that is what he says here. I am not sure he can use change tracking (an Update() call later) if wants to exclude a column. My hunch was that he is using this to pass on through a web API. In that case, he can remap it back if it is large data.

Answer (score 1):

> I only need TeachingProgrammeFile Name and Id

Your query as it stands will give you a fully populated TeachingProgramme with list of Files (including content) back, because it's effectively what you asked for.

EF does, however, [know how to pare down the query to just what you project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#project-only-properties-you-need), for example like:

```
var q = _context.TeachingProgrammes
    .Include(x => x.TeachingProgrammeFiles)
    .Where(x => x.Id == request.TeachingProgrammeId)
    .Select(tp => new { tp.Name, tp.Files.Select(tpf => new { tpf.Id, tpf.Name }) });
```

I've not materialized it at this stage so you can pause in the debugger and take a look at the DebugView property of the query (if this if EFcore5)

You should see that EF has prepared a much reduced SQL. Here's one I threw together on a db here (Aircrafts:Flights is 1:M) - the query Q's prepared SQL is showing in the text vizualizer - you can see that only a small number of columns are included despite the actual table being much more full (on the right). Flights has a similarly large numbers of columns.

[image]

I've used an anon object here but the same applies if you want to make a cutdown DTO/POCO with just a couple of props for this purpose; it's one of the reasons why we have a separation between the data entities our DB uses and the data entities our e.g. UI uses

---

Consider also that you might not need the join to TeachingProgramme at all; you can query files by the relation ID that links back to TP; If you send the id/name to the UI, the user types a new name, then when it comes back you can fake a new local entity that represents the file (id and new name), or just update it direct

Note:
Svyatoslav's comment is noteworthy; if EF can work out what joins you ned from what you've written in the Select, you don't need the Include..

Comment: Why I don't like in such answers - they always contains `Include`, which is completely ignored by EF after `Select`. I thought to make similar answer, but OP needs entities for modification. Entities projected via `Select` are not tracked.

Comment: You don't have to pull it down to update it; you can fake a local one, attach it and send the update. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779937/how-to-update-a-single-property-in-entity-framework-core - of cource some people ight say "but that's sooo hard.." but really it's more because it's an edge case. Not storing the bytes in the DB would be a better option iMHO; filesystems are for files

Comment: Yes, mentioned in comments ;) Workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Either `Select()` the columns you want or use [Table Splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting)

> To use table splitting the entity types need to be mapped to the same
> table, have the primary keys mapped to the same columns and at least
> one relationship configured between the primary key of one entity type
> and another in the same table.
>
> **A common scenario for table splitting is using only a subset of the
> columns in the table for greater performance or encapsulation.**