# ExecuteUpdate update lists of objects efcore .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I wonder if the new ExecuteUpdate can update navigation property which is a list?

```
await _unitOfWork.Repositories<Domain.Team>().ExecuteUpdate(
                x => x.Id == request.UpdateTeamMembersDto.Id,
                x => x.SetProperty(x => x.TeamMembers, teamMembers)
);
```

Here there is a many to many relationship between team and employee entities, TeamMembers is the intermidate table, so i want to update the list of TeamMembers using ExecuteUpdate because I didn't want to retrieve all the related data before updating them.

Update in this context mean Add/Remove TeamMembers from the Team by removing or adding new record to the TeamMembers property.

Another question ExecuteUpdate does not wait for SaveContext to save the changes, can i change this behavior so that if something goes wrong in the transaction the tables don't get effected?

This method is relatively new so i didn't found a complex use case for it like this.

Comment: `ExecuteUpdate` is not foryour case. Your scenario is attach and mark single property as modified like answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52520496/10646316)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is just a test to check it, spoiler:

**No, you can not update navigation properties (Relationships) using `ExecuteUpdate`.**

```cs
public class UnitTest1
{
    private readonly BloggingContext db;
    private readonly Blog blog;
    private readonly List<Post> posts;
    public UnitTest1()
    {
        db = new BloggingContext();
        db.Database.EnsureCreated();
        blog = new Blog() {Url="1"};
        posts = new (){ new Post(){Title="c"}, new Post(){Title="d"}};
        db.Blogs.Add(blog);
        var n = db.SaveChanges();
        Assert.Equal(1, n);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1() // <-- as usual
    {
        blog.Posts.AddRange(posts);
        var n = db.SaveChanges();
        Assert.Equal(2, n);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2() // <-- bulk
    {        
        var n = db.Blogs
            .Where(b => b.BlogId == blog.BlogId)
            .ExecuteUpdate(
                b => b.SetProperty(b => b.Posts, b => posts));
        Assert.Equal(2, n);
    }
}
```

> Failed!  - Failed:     1, Passed:     1, Skipped:     0, Total:     2, Duration: 21 ms

- Test 1 passed.
- Test 2 error:

```
  Error Message:
   System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Blog>()
    .Where(b => b.BlogId == __blog_BlogId_0)
    .ExecuteUpdate(b => b.SetProperty<List<Post>>(
        propertyExpression: b => b.Posts, 
        valueExpression: b => __posts_1))' could not be translated. Additional information: The following 'SetProperty' failed to translate: 'SetProperty(b => b.Posts, b => __posts_1)'. Translation of member 'Posts' on entity type 'Blog' failed. This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

[Full test code at gist](https://gist.github.com/ctrl-alt-d/1110aef925aae980b413ac1b8c63ead2)